# How do I uncheck the "Send to mobile" box in Facebook by default?

Tags: facebook, mobile

Recently, when sending messages on Facebook, I have noticed that the checkmark box next to the "*Send to mobile*" option is on by default. This happens regardless of how many times I uncheck the box.

An illustration of the issue:
[image: "Send to mobile" is checked by default]

How do I change the default behaviour so that the "*Send to mobile*" box is unchecked?

Answer (score 1):

This does seem to be a problem for new messages, however for replying I cannot seem to get that option.

[image: No phone option shown]

Comment: I think it depends, but I can't quite figure out on what. On certain contacts it behaves as you described, but on others it's checked even for replies.

Answer (score 1):

Whether that option is available when replying depends on whether the recipient has registered a mobile device and enabled receiving notifications on it. When sending a new message Facebook doesn't check first and just enables it by default. As far as I can find there is no way to disable this option.